# Automatically wrap cell content

Tags: html, css

I want to populate some text inside a cell of a table, and my data is something like this

```
object1 -> object2 -> object3 ....................-> objectn
```

I dont want to increase the cell size with the number of objects, instead i want to wrap it properly with the cell.

Im using this .css snippet for this purpose

```
.cellbreak {
  max-width: 300px;
  white-space: normal; /* css-3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

But the problem is, my text is breaking without any sense, I mean my output is something like this

```
object1 -> object2 -> obje
ct3 -> object4 ->object5 -
> object6 -> object7 ->obj
ect
```

But I want my output to be like this

```
object1 -> object2 -> object3 ->
object4 -> object5 -> object6 ->
```

How to modify my css to that I get the desirable output.

Note: I have already seen some posts in stackoverflow, but I dint get anything related to my problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you actually using a `table` or just `div`s?

Comment: your use of word-wrap:break-word, does as it is named, breaks a word apart in order to make it wrap, take that out and the words wont break.

Comment: What browser generated the output above?  Every browser I tested broke on the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `word-wrap: break-word;`

If you specify a `max-width` for your element (as you have) then the text inside should wrap normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your style

```
word-break: normal;
```

This property will not break words in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all of your white-space, word-flow, and overflow statements from the CSS because it's not doing what you expect.  Just replace the spaces between the object name and the "->" with [&nbsp;](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

e.g.

```
object1&nbsp;-> object2&nbsp;-> object3&nbsp;-> object4&nbsp;-> object5&nbsp;-> object6&nbsp;->
```

&nbsp; is a Non-Breaking Whitespace character which is to say it won't be broken.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/tTpRW/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what “wrap it properly” means, i.e. which line breaking points are allowed, then implement this using various [ways](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html) of allowing or disallowing line breaks.

Assuming in this case that each “objectk ->” should be kept on one line, then you can use

```
<style>
.nobr { white-space: nowrap }
</style>
<span class=nobr>object1 -></span> <span class=nobr>object2 -></span>
<span class=nobr>object3</span> ....................-> <span class=nobr>objectn</span>
```

If it is permissible to have “->” at the start of a line, too, then you need a little more of those `span` elements.

In the general case, there is no essentially simpler way (unless you cound the use of `<nobr>...</nobr>` instead of `<span class=nobr>...</span>`, a little shorter and a little more robust, but declared nonstandard). Replacing spaces by no-break spaces (`&nbsp;`) might look a bit simpler, but it only works in simple cases. For example, browsers could still break after or before various special characters, perhaps even breaking “>-” in two lines. (You could avoid this specific problem by using the arrow character “→” instead, which might be a good idea for other reasons, too.)